# Web page orientation change when zooming in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

In most of the websites, When we zoom in the orientation of the web page changes. Or you can say when we open that webpage in a smart phone the orientation is different from that of PC. The page is made to fit in the screen. like in this website, [prabhunatarajan.com](http://www.prabhunatarajan.com) , zooming in changes its orientation.

I am new at this. Please someone tell me how to do this.

Comment: This is called [Responsive Web Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using different css files for different sizes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="foo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 601px)" href="foo1.css" />
```

Link for more info http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp